# Change document domain property to make browser tab blink

Tags: javascript, facebook, browser, document

I have a Facebook app running on an inside frame.
I want to make my browser's title to blink when the user goes out from the game's tab.
However, I can't set the document.title property because I have a different domain than 'Facebook.com'.
I have a JS function to change the document title and it works fine when I'm not in a different frame.
How can I make this work for me with the current situation (when I'm in a different frame and need to make the browser's tab blink)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. And you should not do that. It's really annoying for the people using your app.

Comment: It is. When the Facebook Canvas app is loaded from the Facebook chrome, using an iFrame, you can't change the tab-title.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few link worth looking at:
 - http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=404146,
 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout,
 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus,
 - http://javascript.info/tutorial/focus,
 - [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active),
 - [Make browser tab flash a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371016/make-browser-tab-flash-a-notification),
 - [Make browser window blink in task Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar),

cheers