# How to change color of brower tab?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I built a chat that it is working very well but one client has asked me to highlight and/or blink the tab bar of the browser where he has a chat user logged when a visitor calls him. This would be a way to respond the visitor quickly.
So anyone of you fellows knows how to implement such a function in jquery ? I have searched a lot but by now I've not succeeded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make browser tab flash a notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371016/make-browser-tab-flash-a-notification)

Comment: I dnt think this is possible

Comment: As an alternative, you might want to suggest using the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API).

Comment: You can use `alert()` in most browsers that will make the the tab active, but its not a nice ux, I would use push notifications

Answer (score 0):

You can change your favicon. You cannot alter the browser tab.

Comment: Or you could have the title blink.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I did not know that. You have an appropriate username.